# Unity moving in a list of nodes but not reseting after first iteration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm kind of newcomer to Unity and c#, but managed to follow some guidelines and tutorials to get a proper grid and a pathfinding system.

The problem is when I click to move one object, **it properly moves,  but the second time I try to move** from the new position to another, the pathfinder does always resend the first path. I tried to clear the list of nodes after first move and debug.log the input data sent to pathfinder class and it's correct, the list of nodes received is always the same first one.

I can paste the code but it's just the usual A* pathfinding one, and it works but just for the first path.

In the update I use this, with *pathfinding.currentPath* returning a list of nodes that properly updates in other tests I did that do not require moving logic:

```
        if (moving) {
        MovingLogic ();

    } else {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            targetIndex = 1;

            //Debug.Log (transform.position + " :: " + mouseManager.GetTileWorldPointFromMouse ());


            pathfinding.WalkableNodes (transform.position, mouseManager.GetTileWorldPointFromMouse (), maxMovement);
            finalPath = pathfinding.currentPath;

            //int i = 0;
            //while (i <= finalPath.Count - 1) {
            //Debug.Log (finalPath [i].gridX + "," + finalPath [i].gridY);
            //i++;
            //}

            //Debug.Log (" -- " + finalPath.Count);
            moving = true;

        }


    }
```

The moving logic function is:

```
    void MovingLogic(){

    if (!initLerp) {

        if (targetIndex == finalPath.Count) { // goal reached
            targetIndex = 1;
            moving = false;

            //pathfinding.currentPath.Clear();
            //path.Clear();
            finalPath.Clear();

            return;
        }
        moveT = 0;
        startPosT = this.transform.position;

        targetPosT = finalPath [targetIndex].worldPosition;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance (startPosT, targetPosT);
        speedActual = speed / distance;
        initLerp = true;
    }

    moveT += Time.deltaTime * speedActual;

    if(moveT > 1){
        moveT = 1;
        initLerp = false;

        if (targetIndex < finalPath.Count -1)
            targetIndex++;
        else
            moving = false;

    }
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp (startPosT, targetPosT, moveT);
    transform.position = newPos;

}
```

Comment: `I can paste the code but it's just the usual A* pathfinding one, and it works but just for the first path.` Can anyone answer your question without providing your code? Read your question and try to answer it.

Comment: Stop using A* until you have a better understanding of AI and pathfinding algorithms, and instead use the Unity Navmesh.

Comment: It's a 2D grid based movement for a board game. I'll edit the question qith the code.